# Bold mathematics in eulervm

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold, eulervm

The `eulervm` package documentation indicates that one should use `\mathbold` instead of `\mathbf` to produce bold maths.

Could one write `\renewcommand{\mathbf}{\mathbold}`? What are the side effects?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Since these require a parameter, you'll need to use `\let\mathbf\mathbold`, or use `letltxmacro`.

Comment: Thank you Peter for the answer. The renewcommand as I stated does work. I have tested it. I guess my question was more about the reason for introducing \mathbold. I am no expert on fonts in LaTeX.

Comment: @PeterGrill The `\renewcommand` method is perfectly good; why shouldn't it be? There's no requirement that a renewed command should have the same number of arguments as the original.

Comment: @egreg: I realize that it works in this case, but I find is confusing that then you have a definition as `\renewcommand{\foo}{}` which sort of implies there are no parameters, but needs to be used as `\foo{}`. Using `\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{#1}` clarifies that. Also using the `let` syntax it is not confusing as then just a new name is being redefined.  I prefer to make the intent clearer even if it requires more characters to minimize any potential confusion

Comment: @PeterGrill The two commands *don't* take arguments! It *may* be confusing, but it's really the best way to cope with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard definition for `\mathbf` is

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

This has the effect that math symbols declared as `\mathalpha` (essentially Latin letters, uppercase Greek letters, digits and accents) that happen to be in the argument of `\mathbf` are typeset from the stated font.

The `eulervm` package uses a different font for bold:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}
```

and also redeclares many symbols (for instance, also lowercase Greek letter are allowed in the argument of `\mathbold`).

Since the effect of `\mathbold` is different from `\mathbf` it's a good decision to use a different name. However

```
\renewcommand{\mathbf}{\mathbold}
```

is perfectly safe. What happens is that when TeX sees `\mathbf` it replaces it by `\mathbold` and then proceeds to look for the arguments to `\mathbold`. (Actually, as Werner showed, there's no argument to `\mathbold`, but this is immaterial.)

With this redefinition you lose the original meaning of `\mathbf`, but using `eulervm` it doesn't seem to be important. Would you keep it for some reason, it's better to say

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\originalmathbf}{\mathbf}
```

before redefining `\mathbf`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can write `\renewcommand{\mathbf}{\mathbold}`. Why? Let's look at the definitions of both (using a definition of `\pshow` from [The definitions of LaTeX commands](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds) on the [TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-startup)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds
\pshow\mathbf
\usepackage{eulervm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm
\pshow\mathbold
\makeatletter
\show\select@group
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Dummy text.
\end{document}
```

yields in the `.log`:

```
> \mathbf =macro:
->\select@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n .
\mathbf ->\protect \mathbf  
                            
l.3 \pshow\mathbf
                 

(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eulervm/eulervm.sty
Package: eulervm 2005/01/11 v4.0 (WaS)
)
> \mathbold =macro:
->\select@group \mathbold  \M@U \U/zeur/b/n .
\mathbold ->\protect \mathbold  
                                
l.5 \pshow\mathbold
                   

> \select@group=macro:
#1#2#3#4->\ifx \math@bgroup \bgroup \else \relax \expandafter \@firstofone \fi 
{\ifmmode \ifnum \csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname <\sixt@@n \begingroup \e
scapechar \m@ne \getanddefine@fonts {\csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname }#3    globaldefs \@ne \math@fonts \endgroup \init@restore@version \xdef #1{\noexpand 
\use@mathgroup \noexpand #2{\number \csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname }}\gl
obal \advance \csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname \@ne \else \let #1\relax \@
latex@error {Too many math alphabets used in version \math@version }\@eha \fi     else \expandafter \non@alpherr \fi #1{#4}}.
l.7 \show\select@group
```

Note that neither `\mathbf` nor `\mathbold` take an argument. There is a secondary macro called from both `\mathbf` and `\mathbold` that takes the argument supplied: `\select@group`. The first three arguments taken by `\select@group` is supplied within `\mathbf` and `\mathbold`, while the fourth is supplied additionally after each macro.

What are the side effects? You can't use the original definition of `\mathbf`. Some people circumvent this by using

```
\let\oldmathbf\mathbf% Store contents of \mathbf in \oldmathbf
\let\mathbf\mathbold% Rename \mathbf to \mathbold
```

Comment: The fact that `\mathbf` and `\mathbold` don't have arguments is irrelevant. With `\renewcommand{\mathbf}{\mathbold}` you just tell TeX to change the former into the latter when expanding macros; only after this replacement TeX will start looking for arguments to `\mathbold` (of which there aren't, but it's another matter).

Comment: @Werner Thanks for explaining how these commands work.

Answer (score 1):

The `eulervm` package chooses to separate the ideas of bold words in math mode, and bold math symbols such as vectors.  The `unicode-math` package does something similar: if you load Neo Euler as your math font, you can use `\symbfup` for bold math symbols, or `\mathbf` for bold words in math mode.

In practice, though, you have the AMS text commands if you want to insert emphasized text( for example, `\textbf{ iff }` for a strongly-emphasized **iff**. So you do not really lose anything by redefining  `mathbf` to make math symbols, rather than words.

Comment: Thank you for the precision.