# `eulervm` and bold theorems

Tags: bold, newtheorem, eulervm

I use `concrete-roman` as in Knuth's *Concrete Mathematics* as my main font. However, it does not come with a math font, so I include `eulervm` for it.

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{concrete}% the concrete-roman, used in concrete mathetics
\usepackage{eulervm}% the math fonts used in concrete mathematics
```

This has gone well until I tried to boldify my theorems. Namely, instead of

> Theorem 4.1. 1+1 = 2

I want

> **Theorem 4.1.** 1+1 = 2.

For this, I added the following command to header copying from
[How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43966/how-to-make-the-optional-title-of-a-theorem-bold-with-amsthm)

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {}%                                     % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {.}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
```

It does not work.

If I remove `eulervm`, then the theorems do get boldified. However, the fonts fall back to some default ones..

#### Question

How to I remain in the la-la-land of `concrete+eulervm` fonts, with boldified theorems?

---

#### possibly related

It's pointed out in [Bold mathematics in eulervm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63017/bold-mathematics-in-eulervm) that `eulervm` handles bold fonts differently. But they only addressed bold math fonts..

---

#### Minimal example

Below is a minimal example that compiles with `$ pdflatex`. You can toggle `eulervm` to see the effects described in my question. Notice that `mystyle` is indeed working: disabling `\theoremstyle{mystyle}` changes the font of the body to italic (default).

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{concrete}% the concrete-roman, used in concrete mathetics
\usepackage{eulervm}% the math fonts used in concrete mathematics

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {}%                                     % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {.}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  The sum of $1$ and $1$ is $2$.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site yo are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here there is no document class or sample document body.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have just added one!

Comment: Short answer: chance `\usepackage{concrete}` to `\usepackage{ccfonts}`. Longer answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425887/61644

Comment: @Davislor thanks for reaching out! I did it, but theorems are still not boldified.

Comment: Replace the theorem-style definition with `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`.

Comment: What error messages are you getting in the log? Are there any messages about a /b/n font missing, and defaults being substituted?

Comment: @Davislor removing `[equation]` as you suggested did not help. However, there is indeed a warning message about fonts! `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ccr/b/n' undefined \n
(Font)              using `OT1/ccr/m/n' instead on input line 22. \n
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ccr/m/up' undefined \n
(Font)              using `OT1/ccr/m/n' instead on input line 22.`. How would I fix such issue?

Comment: Okay, I found the problem and posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a bit into the font description files, I found the reason bold substitutions were not working.  Concrete does not come in bold, and the font package only declares a substitution for the `/bx/n` series and shape in the `T1` encoding.  By default, you were trying to use `/b/n` of `OT1`.

You can therefore replace the command

```
\usepackage{concrete}
```

with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bx}
```

I would recommend you use `unicode-math` and LuaLaTeX where you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts when you have to, though.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425887/61644) for several longer examples.

Since you are defining your own theorem style, you could instead select the font of your choice for its headers, such as, here, Latin Modern Sans-Serif Semi-bold Condensed:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ccfonts}% the concrete-roman, used in concrete mathetics
\usepackage{eulervm,eucal,eufrak}% the math fonts used in concrete mathematics

\renewcommand\bfdefault{bx}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {}%                                     % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\usefont{T1}{lmss}{sbc}{n}}%           % Theorem head font
  {.}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%                                 % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  The sum of $1$ and $1$ is $2$.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```